# Webapp - Best method to limite usage of user

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I'm building a webapp where I would like to limit the user of over using the application.

I would like to limit how many time the user send email notification each month.

The way I was thinking of doing this is by logging every notification with user_id date time.
So before Sending a notification I will select * WHERE user_id Between Date and Date+30.
And do a validation that the number of entry is smaller then the limit.

Is there an easy and faster way to do this.
I'm a bit nervous when I will have 1/2 millions logging entry.

Comment: seems like a sound approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

This types of problem is perfect for Redis to solve.

Basically you can have a cache item for each user, and then increment it every time the user sends an email. The cache item would expire at the end of the month. You can read this cache item whenever you want. This way you don't need any database table or queries, and the speed should be super fast.

If you want to precisely limit the user over the "previous 30 day" period, things get a little more complicated. In that situation, you log a user event by dumping it into a sorted set in Redis, keyed off the user's id. Then you can use the ZCOUNT function on the sorted set to figure out how many events had occurred for this user in the preceding 30 days precisely. The score is would be the time stamp of the event, of course.

BTW, a Redis system is incredibly easy to install, and may not need any configuration in your situation.

Comment: Is Redis system are faster then mysql.

Comment: The underlying data structure should be the same (an indexed dataset like a btree or something like that), so the algorithm performance should be on par between Redis and MySQL. The added advantage is the Redis most likely would perform the operation in memory, and it doesn't have MySQL's ACID requirements, so I'd say there is a slight advantage to Redis.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I will try Redis this weekend before installing online on my production server.